# How do i fadeIn a grid of images on scroll in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a grid of images that i want to fadein when the images come into view on scroll with JQuery fadeIn, here is my current code,[JS Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/0bakxdr9/1/)

I have tried using this code but i cant get it working.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll( function(){

        $(".vw").each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

            }

        }); 

    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="grid">
    <div class="vw">
        <img src="http://th08.deviantart.net/fs71/200H/i/2012/190/b/7/bastique_graffiti_art_car__02__golf_mkv_r32_by_bastiqueart-d56k7iu.jpg" width="300" height="169" />
    </div>
    <div class="vw">
        <img src="http://th08.deviantart.net/fs71/200H/i/2012/190/b/7/bastique_graffiti_art_car__02__golf_mkv_r32_by_bastiqueart-d56k7iu.jpg" width="300" height="169" />
    </div>
    <div class="vw">
        <img src="http://th08.deviantart.net/fs71/200H/i/2012/190/b/7/bastique_graffiti_art_car__02__golf_mkv_r32_by_bastiqueart-d56k7iu.jpg" width="300" height="169" />
    </div>
    <div class="vw">
        <img src="http://th08.deviantart.net/fs71/200H/i/2012/190/b/7/bastique_graffiti_art_car__02__golf_mkv_r32_by_bastiqueart-d56k7iu.jpg" width="300" height="169" />
    </div>
    <div class="vw">
        <img src="http://th08.deviantart.net/fs71/200H/i/2012/190/b/7/bastique_graffiti_art_car__02__golf_mkv_r32_by_bastiqueart-d56k7iu.jpg" width="300" height="169" />
    </div>
    <div class="vw">
        <img src="http://th08.deviantart.net/fs71/200H/i/2012/190/b/7/bastique_graffiti_art_car__02__golf_mkv_r32_by_bastiqueart-d56k7iu.jpg" width="300" height="169" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .vw {
        position: relative;
        float:left;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        width:300px;
        height:169px;
    }
    #grid {
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color:green;
        width:900px;
        height:2366px;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+check+when+element+in+view

Comment: I have rewritten it, can it be reopened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the jquery.appear plugin: http://morr.github.io/appear.html

It adds an `appear` event that you can bind to.

```
<div id='scrollOver'>This might be lower on the page</div>
$('#scollOver').appear();
$('#scrollOver').on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
  // this element is now inside browser viewport
  alert('Now visible!');
});
```

**Edit**: Here's a fiddle for you to try: http://jsfiddle.net/nzt5hqd2/

Comment: Are you seeing errors in the console? Have you included the JS libraries correctly? I need more information to help you with the problem.